# Uniq liquid filter tag won't work when looping words in string

Tags: tags, liquid, uniq

I want to list all the tags from my posts, and of course with only one of every tag, so there is not several of one tag.

I tried putting it in a string, for separating them with a space, and then loop every word out from the string, giving them the uniq filter:

```
{% capture alltags %}

{% for story in site.stories %}

{{ story.tags | join: ' ' }}

{% endfor %}

{% endcapture %}

{% for word in alltags %}

{{ word | uniq }}

{% endfor %}
```

I get the spaces between the words, but they are not uniq.
I do need them to be looped individually so i can make a link on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work.

```
{% comment %} compiling the gross list of all tags, duplicates and all {% endcomment %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign tags = tags | concat:post.tags %}
{% endfor %}
{% comment %} Getting rid of duplicates (uniq), sorting it  - all in one go {% endcomment %}
{{ tags | uniq | sort }}
```

Comment: The uniq is working in this thanks, but they are not separated anymore. Cause we need them to be linked individually so if you click on them it filters with the tag. If i put a <a> on {{ tags | uniq | sort }} it puts the link around all the words..

Answer (score 3):

If you try this, you will understand what's happening.

```
{% capture alltags %}
{% for story in site.stories %}
{{ story.tags | join: ' ' }}
{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

alltags : {{ alltags | inspect }}

{% for word in alltags %}
word : {{ word | inspect }}

uniq : {{ word | uniq }}
{% endfor %}
```

`alltags` is a string, not an array.

When you loop over `alltags`, the only loop that happen contains `word` variable which is a string equal to `alltags` itself.

In fact you need to apply `uniq` filter on an array.

If your run this code, you will see the difference :

```
{% comment %} create an empty array {% endcomment %}
{% assign tagsArray = "" | split:"" %}

{% for story in site.stories %}
  {% assign tagsArray = tagsArray | concat: story.tags %}
  tagsArray : {{ tagsArray | inspect }}
{% endfor %}

tagsArray : {{ tagsArray | inspect }}

{% assign tagsArray = tagsArray | uniq %}

tagsArray uniq : {{ tagsArray | inspect }}
```